# How to match an object with specific shape and cut it out from image?

Tags: python, opencv, match, extract, shapes

Well, I have a problem with finding a solution to this one. I want to match specific shape of object on image and cut it out. Object is not in the same place all the time. There are small differences.. also it can be smaller than the one which is compared with. Another problem is the background which has similar pixel intensivity and segmentation doesn't work as it should(it takes all the object pixels and some from the background). I need to get rid of those pixels which are not the object pixels. That's why I would like to match with the "template" and cut out the exact shape of it with no background. Is it possible?
[image]
I've tried few segmentation methods but it doesn't work. Those pixels above the object have similar intensivity to those which are object pixels. I've tried morphology operations but it doesn't work either.[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use a low pass filter to get rid of those pixels above the object?

Comment: @HemersonTacon Not yet Sir. How should I use it? Before thresholding? Is it possible that low pass filter will help me to get rid off only those pixels which are connected with background?

Comment: @HemersonTacon Just checked it. It makes line smoother and probably helps a little but contours are not as straight as I want them to be. But thanks :) I wasn't sure about low pass filters but then I understood that I've actually used them before :)

Comment: I think you can use a high pass filter in the original image to enhance the contours, keep this image, use a low pass in the original image to eliminate the "pepper and salt"-like noise and then add the result of the high pass with the result of the low pass to get back de contours. (I know that is possible to do something like this but don't know exactly if these are the right steps)